# complete authors details not showing up at title page in BMC latex templet

Tags: latex

I am using BMC latex template. I use two author details in the template. However, the BMC template only shows up the details of correspondence.

I want to show up Name, emails, addresses of both authors at the title page.

Please help how to solve this issue.[image: authors detail in latex file]
[image: authors details in pdf]

Comment: Where is the *BMC template*?